# Story about a clockwork fencing robot that becomes unbeatable and kills its inventor

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall reading a story about an inventor that makes a clockwork fencing robot that gets so good that it kills the inventor.

I want to say it was a short story. The story had to do with an inventor making a fencing robot that worked solely off of the power of the inventor fencing with it, in a clockwork fashion.

The inventor fenced with the robot and, after each session, shut it off and fine-tuned it to be a better fencer. I believe the story ended with the inventor dying as there was no way for the inventor to reach the off button because the robot had been fine-tuned to the point it was unbeatable in fencing.

Comment: Do you remember anything about it? Time period? Was the inventor the protagonist? The victim? Is the story framed so that it's about his fight or about people dealing with the scene?

Comment: Almost sounds like a story inside the girl genius universe. There was the muse of justice that was a fencing clank.

Comment: Gil has built his owning fencing clank (and has to cheat when he accidentally escalates it) and Agatha also builds her own fencing robot, albeit largely to keep Zeetha away so she can sleep.

Comment: Was it a short story or a novel? Did you read in in the 1940s, 1950s, or 1960s?

Comment: @SeanDuggan but the one I'm thinking of was the one that became the castle eventually.

Comment: This is almost exactly a sub plot in the dune prequel bulterian jihad trilogy

Comment: This makes me think of the fencing machine that Alia fights in *Dune Messiah*.  It has no upper bound to its speed/ability, it's up to the user to know when to turn it off.

Comment: @DavidW: that yes, and also the sword-fighting robot in StickManStickMan https://stickman.qntm.org/comics.php?n=198